# tortoiseSVN slow after update to 1.6.5

Tags: tortoise-svn

Previously I had tortoiseSVN 1.4.6. I upgraded my tortoiseSVN to 1.6.5. All operations like commit, checkout slowed down. It waits about 16-17 seconds and then suddenly completes the operation.

The repositories are on our company server managed by our IT department. Do they also have to update their subversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a significant change in version.  [This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042799/migrating-svn-1-4-repos-to-1-6-populating-node-origins) talks about migrating from 1.4 to 1.6.  The slowdown you are seeing may very well be due to differences in the repository version Tortoise is trying to deal with on the fly.  Checkout the [upgrade release notes](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html).